# Access denied pushing images to gcr repository

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

No matter what I do I can't push images to google repository. I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling?hl=en_GB&_ga=2.203941712.-1906676109.1520523701&_gac=1.209530406.1520523703.EAIaIQobChMIw5XAr4jd2QIVxqgYCh1QUgekEAAYASAAEgJFCvD_BwE) and I do these commands directly from the google cloud shell

```
docker build -t eu.gcr.io/[project-id]/[imagename]:[tag] ~/[folder]
docker tag eu.gcr.io/[project-id]/[imagename]:[tag] eu.gcr.io/[project-id]/[imagename]:[tag]
docker push eu.gcr.io/[project-id]/[imagename]:[tag]
```

I get this output when pushing

```
4d1ea31bd998: Preparing
03b6a2b0817c: Preparing
104044bed4c7: Preparing
2222fefcbbfc: Preparing
75166708bd17: Preparing
5eefc1b802bb: Waiting
5c33df241050: Waiting
ffc4c11463ee: Waiting
denied: Unable to access the repository, please check that you have permission to access it.
```

I've search for this online but everyone seems to have authentication issues. Since I can't execute this neither from my local machine or the google cloud shell I don't think there's a problem there since when I'm on the shell I'm using the owner account [owner]@[project-id]. I have billing and Container Registry API active

From my understanding pushing should create a bucket for this but I even tried creating a bucket but I have no idea if and how to configure it to be used for image repository. I have billing and Container Registry API activated

Comment: Have you tried `docker login eu.gcr.io` before pushing?

Comment: Not really. Didn't find any reference to that. I'll google that

Comment: Could you try that out? Just type it in the console.

Comment: god damn it, it worked. Thank you so much, I'm really new to gcr and I've been stuck here for a day now.

Comment: Glas I could help. It should have been in the guide, though. Perhaps you can give them some feedback for the guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably did not authenticate with the registry. Please try to login before pushing. Just type in the console and enter your credentials:

```
docker login eu.gcr.io
```

Comment: In my experience, running this command _once_ locally, after I activated the service account, allowed authentication to work _everywhere_ for that service account.